# Div Hide/Show with radio button click using Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Here is my code:

class File_Form_AddFile extends Custom_Form {

```
public function init() {

    $translate = Zend_Registry::get('translate');
    $this->setTranslator($translate);
    $this->setName("addfile");
    $this->setMethod('post');


    $this->addElement('text', 'title', array(
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', false, array(0, 50)),
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => __('Title') . ':',
    ));


    $this->addElement('radio', 'type', array(
        'label'=>__('Applicant Type'),
        'multiOptions' => array(
            'office' => 'Office',
            'community' => 'Community',
            'person' => 'Person',
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'separator' => '',
        'value' => 'office'
    ));


    **// I want this section to show only after 'community' is clicked at above input field.**

    $this->addElement('radio', 'community_is_registered', array(
        'label'=>__('Registered Community?'),
        'multiOptions' => array(
            1 => 'Yes',
            0 => 'No',
        ),
        'separator' => '',
        'value' =>'0'
    ));


    $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', false, array(0, 100)),
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'label' => __('Applicant Name') . ':',
    ));



    $this->addElement('submit', 'save', array(
        'required' => false,
        'ignore' => true,
        'label' => __('Save'),
    ));
    $this->save->removeDecorator('label');
}
```

}

This is a form to add some information of a file. Here i want to show the section of "Registered Community?" only after the button "Community" is clicked at "Applicant Type". Seeing for help !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want certain behavior to occur on the client-side based upon certain actions taking place on the client-side, it seems to be fundamentally a client-side question.

Perhaps the easiest thing is to:

1. Add a certain CSS class to the Registered Community element (or display group, if it's a collection of elements) during server-side form creation.
2. Use front-end CSS to hide all form elements of that class.
3. Add a client-side on-click handler to the "Applicant Type" element that removes/changes the class or shows/hides the "Registered Community" section when the "Applicant Type" has the desired value.

Comment: Dear David, yeah it is possible using normal html form at view page. But i wonder can we do that in Zend form? Since here at zend form, i am not finding a way to assign id to particular div containing some input fields.

Comment: Using `Zend_Form`, the typical approach would be to place all the fields for that section into a display group. Then you can set up the decorators for that display group to render the CSS id/class on the containing div/fieldset. Then the client-side approach above should work.